# why not change display when override django admin template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I followed [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/#enter-the-admin-site) to change the `base_site.html`  template ,but no effect.here is the codes:

**The project structure:**

```
-myproject
  -myproject
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  -myapp1
  -myapp2
  -templates
    -admin
      base_site.html
```

**setttings.py:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    }
]
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
)
```

**base_site.html**

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}custom title{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">MY custom website name</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

when this is done,refresh the page, the title and site name doesnt change,can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to override `base_site.html`

**project structure**(same as yours)

```
-myproject
  -myproject
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  -myapp1
  -myapp2
  -templates
    -admin
      base_site.html
```

**In settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
)
```

**In `base_site.html`**(same as yours)

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}custom title{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">MY custom website      name</a></h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

That is no need of `TEMPLATES=[]` as you defined.I think that is used for `specific` apps.

Comment: you solution is worked,but what does app specified means?how this TEMPLATES=() works? if set TMPLATES,does that mean building templates directory under every app ?

Comment: Another question,There is an alternative,which is django recommends,that is using django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite,by default ,this is django.contrib.admin.site which is to set the global settings,but for good design pattern,where should i put the global setting?for example,admin.site.site_title = 'My Admin Site',although i can put this into any app's admin.py file,but where is the best?

Comment: I think `TEMPLATES=()` is used for extending `templates` in admin to our `app` templates.Like `{% extends "admin:admin/base_site.html" %}`.Find here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-apptemplates/